# NASM assembly, How to print the first 4 bytes of a string array

Tags: arrays, assembly, nasm

If `names` is an array of a string of names stored like this:
TomBobPeterJim. How can I separate and push each name separately? Each name takes up 4 bytes right? This is what I tried, but it prints the entire line:

```
      ;printf("Name %d:\t%s\n",x+1,names[x]);

      mov ecx, dword x
      mov edx, names
      lea ebx, [edx+ecx*4]
      push ebx
      inc ecx
      push ecx
      push szOut
      call _printf
      add esp, 12
```

Comment: How is `Peter` four bytes?

Comment: Could u show a simple example in code please?

Comment: The names need to be terminated by zero. Either fix the name data or have the names array of pointers to the data include a pointer to an extra name of all zeroes. Then save name[x+1], name[x+1] = 0, print, restore name[x+1].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put a zero after the end of each name (save the character there first). Example where char *names[] is defined at assemble time, Microsoft syntax:

```
        .data
name0   db      "Tom"
name1   db      "Bob"
name2   db      "Peter"
name3   db      "Jim"
nameend db      0
szOut   db      "%d %s",00ah,000h
        align   4                       ;put on 4 byte boundary
names   dd      name0, name1, name2, name3, nameend
numnam  dd      ($-names)/4 - 1         ;in this case, numnam == 4
x       dd      0
        .code
        extern  _printf:proc
_main   proc    near
        xor     ebx,ebx                 ;bh == 0
        mov     ecx, x                  ;esi = ptr to name
main0:
        mov     esi, names[ecx*4]
        mov     edi, names+4[ecx*4]     ;edi = ptr to end name
        mov     bl, [edi]               ;save last char
        mov     [edi],bh                ;set zero
        push    esi                     ;display name
        push    ecx
        push    offset szOut
        call    _printf
        add     esp, 12
        mov     [edi],bl                ;restore last char
        inc     x                       ;loop till done
        mov     ecx,x
        cmp     ecx,numnam
        jnz     main0
        xor     eax,eax
        ret
```